# Interchange loop variable with if statement

Tags: c++

I'm trying to change a for loop's start variable to use an if statement instead. However, they don't seem to be equivalent..

I have a loop that looked like:

```
int K = 0;
std::uint32_t CheckSum = 0;
const std::uint8_t* BuffPos = static_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(Data);
int Start = Height < 12 ? 1 : 12;

for (std::size_t I = Start; I < Height; ++I)
{
    for (std::size_t J = 0; J < Width; ++J, ++K)
    {
        BuffPos += 3;  //skip RGB and move to alpha pixel.
        CheckSum += *(BuffPos++);  //Checksum = count of alpha pixels.
    }
}

std::cout<<CheckSum;
```

However, I don't want my loop to start with `I = Start`.
I'd rather do that in an if statement. I tried the following:

```
int K = 0;
std::uint32_t CheckSum = 0;
const std::uint8_t* BuffPos = static_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(Data);
int Start = Height < 12 ? 1 : 12;

for (std::size_t I = 0; I < Height; ++I)
{
    for (std::size_t J = 0; J < Width; ++J, ++K)
    {
        BuffPos += 3; //Skip RGB and move to alpha pixel.

        if (I >= Start)  //The if statement.
            CheckSum += *(BuffPos++);  //Checksum = count of alpha pixels.
    }
}

std::cout<<CheckSum;
```

However, the second version with the if statement prints a totally different number than the first for the exact same bitmap.

Is there a reason why it does this? How can I fix it? I can't see why it would be any different :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, it is no longer the same.

Sure, you segregated the checksum bit, but now you are incrementing `BufPos` a different number of times.  Your loop is now iterating more times, so `BuffPos` has a different value once you start creating the checksum than it did in the first version.

Look at it this way; the first version starts accumulating the checksum at `BuffPos + 3`.  The second version begins accumulating the checksum from `BuffPos + (Start * Width) + 3`.

Honestly, the first version is better.  I can't tell you which one is *correct*, but assuming the first version is (iterating from `Start`) then why introduce a branch at all?  It just muddles up the code.

If you want the second version to be the same as the first you'll need to initialize `BuffPos` to `Data + Start * Width` or place both statements within the `if`.  Of course, if you do that, you're just doing nothing at all until `I == Start`, and that should tell you something.

Comment: The branch was so that the first part would calculate a checksum of all pixels and within the branch, I'd calculate a checksum of all except the first 12 rows.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: then why are you surprised that it now gives a different value?  You changed the checksum.  Just set `BuffPos` to point to the correct place to begin with (as I showed).

Comment: I was trying to use the two loops to calculate two checksums rather than looping the image with 4 loops (one checksum starting at row 12. Another starting at row 0).

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Ok, but your example code doesn't do that. We could only answer based on what you show us.

Comment: "I can't tell you which one is correct." deserves a -1 but since this is a recreational question, I'll refrain!

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted: No it doesn't.  I can't tell because I don't know if the OP wants to include every pixel in the checksum or not.  Can you?

Comment: @EdS. hmmm... if that's the case, i'll upvote you once my brain digests it!

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted: Could be that some amount of data in the beginning of the buffer should not be included.  I have no idea.  The only thing I do know is that there is a better way to write that second loop.

Comment: @EdS. i'm too slow at the moment to figure out whether there may be any point/pixel to doing it the way the OP wants, but why take a chance. upvoting you for patience and probable insight! :)

Answer (score 1):

how's this version?

```
int K = 0;
std::uint32_t CheckSum = 0;
const std::uint8_t* BuffPos = static_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(Data);
int Start = Height < 12 ? 1 : 12;

for (std::size_t I = 0; I < Height; ++I)
{
    if (I < Start)  //The if statement.
        continue; 
    for (std::size_t J = 0; J < Width; ++J, ++K)
    {
        BuffPos += 3; //Skip RGB and move to alpha pixel.
        CheckSum += *(BuffPos++);  //Checksum = count of alpha pixels.
    }
}

std::cout<<CheckSum;
```

Comment: *"how's this version?"* - pretty useless.  I know it's what the OP is asking for, but in this case, the OP wants the wrong solution.

Comment: hehe... who am i to deny the OP's desire. did you undownvote? i was mainly wondering what people would do in response. this was a rhetorical answer if there's such a thing. and also a sociological experiment. props for the undownvote - you pass :)

Comment: @EdS. i spoke too soon! either somebody else downvoted, or you unundownvoted.

Comment: I downvoted, removed it... and then downvoted again.  I was a bit conflicted because it's technically what the OP was asking for.  However, it's brain-dead code.  Why introduce cycles which do absolutely nothing?  I would refactor that code in a second, so I don't think it's a good answer.

Comment: @EdS. well, there's might still be time to ununundownvote, lol

Comment: I just did :D.  I'll leave it as a no-op.  Still though... `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) { if (i < 998) continue; DoSomething(); }`. Does that look reasonable to you?

Comment: @EdS. see now i'm missing your upvote! of course, i know the pointlessness. may be it is cold where the OP is and could use some laptop warmth (i've actually done this a couple of times!). thanks for putting up with what i do on a friday night.

Answer (score 0):

Both statements(Buffpos and cheksum) should come under if statement .